# JQuery and Prototype.js conflict

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, prototypejs, bootstrap-select

I need to include prototype.js and jQuery, but that messes up my bootstrap-select.js it seems like, because of some conflicting.

After selecting an option in the select list, it disappears.

I included these js files:

```
jquery-2.1.0.min.js
bootstrap-select.min.js
prototype.min.js
```

And this in the `<head>` section:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function($) {
    $j('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/0vh03tnn/1/

Comment: Please include relevant code IN your question, not only via an external resource.  This is a rule at StackOverflow.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am also including prototype, jquery, noConflict, Bootstrap and Bootstrap select. when I disable prototype bootstrap-select works well. (Bootstrap itself has no problems though).

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the order of things. Include Prototype first, then jQuery, then your block with jQuery.noConflict(), and finally the bootstrap script. The way I understand noConflict is this: whatever $ is bound to, memoize it, then create a jQuery object and a new, untrammeled $ inside that object, and finally return $ to the global scope from what it was to begin with. With the order of things you have here, $ may not point to the Prototype $ function at the moment that noConflict does its thing.